# Code doesn't work after combining two statements

Tags: javascript, undefined, addeventlistener

This is original code:

```
h1tag= document.getElementById("myHeading");       
h1tag.addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{h1tag.style.backgroundColor="blue"});
```

After combining:

```
h1tag= document.getElementById("myHeading").addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{h1tag.style.backgroundColor="blue"});
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Because `addEventListener` *doesn't return anything*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this line :

```
h1tag= document.getElementById("myHeading").addEventListener("mouseover", ()=>{h1tag.style.backgroundColor="blue"});
```

Is that the statement is evaluated from left to right, so the last method that will be called is `addEventListener`, so in other words you are trying to store the returned result from `addEventListener` in your `h1tag` variable while **[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** doesn't have a return type so it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

To expand on the previous answers, the key issue here is that `h1tag` is not defined (because `addEventListener` doesn't return a value) and you are trying to change it's properties.

Fortunately, javascript provides a way to access the element that an event is called on, through an argument passed to the event function.

Try running

```
document.getElementsById("myHeading")
.addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{e.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue"})
```

Answer (score -1):

h1tag is not defined in your second attempt.

```
document.getElementById("myHeading").addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor="blue"});
```

if you still want to kep a reference to the element:

```
(h1tag=document.getElementById("myHeading")).addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{e.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor="blue"});
```